# Are there races other than human?

Tags: my-hero-academia

In *Boku no Hero Academia*, there are many people who have a special appearance, different from a human appearance, like Tokoyami for example.

Is this something normal in the world of *My Hero Academia* where someone can have a different appearance caused by their quirks? Or is it more like in *Dragon Ball* where there are many races that if someone isn't human, other people see it as okay?

Comment: Have you ever heard of/seen other races in the MHA universe? All I've seen are humans, with quirks. A lot of em. So in a world dominated by quirks, it's logical to assume that the quirk factor is the reason.

Comment: In DBZ, there is also no other races per se, they are just 'people' with different appearances

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are quirks. Mostly, transformation quirks. They are human. Though there is a real rat (an animal) character I know. The principal. He was a product of experiments. I don't know if there are other kinds like principal.